# Unexpected image keep appearing

Tags: html, css

I want to combine input and select as well as some arrow beside to make it look pretty. The problem is whenever I hover my mouse over, another copy of my arrow appear inside the text field which confuse me a lot. Even when I disable hoover, it still appear.

[image]

My CSS and HTML:

```css
input {
    /* styling */
    background-color: white;
    border: thin solid blue;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    font: inherit;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
    /* reset */
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

/* arrows */
input.classic {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, blue 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(to right, skyblue, skyblue);
    background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px), calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px), 100% 0;
    background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 2.5em 2.5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input.classic:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(to right, gray, gray);
    background-position: calc(100% - 15px) 1em, calc(100% - 20px) 1em, 100% 0;
    background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 2.5em 2.5em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-color: grey;
    outline: 0;
}

input:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<input class="classic" type="text" name="city" list="cityname" />
<datalist id="cityname">
    <option value="Boston">
    <option value="Cambridge">
</datalist> input {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the default arrow with.

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

Working example.

```css
input {
  /* styling */
  background-color: white;
  border: thin solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5em 3.5em 0.5em 1em;
  /* reset */

  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

/* arrows */

input.classic {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, blue 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, skyblue, skyblue);
  background-position: calc(100% - 20px) calc(1em + 2px),
    calc(100% - 15px) calc(1em + 2px), 100% 0;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 2.5em 2.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input.classic:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, gray, gray);
  background-position: calc(100% - 15px) 1em, calc(100% - 20px) 1em,
    100% 0;
  background-size: 5px 5px, 5px 5px, 2.5em 2.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-color: grey;
  outline: 0;
}

input:-moz-focusring {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input class="classic" type="text" name="city" list="cityname" />
<datalist id="cityname">
  <option value="Boston"></option>
  <option value="Cambridge"></option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this script into your CSS

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```